# Как отрезать .php в адресах сайта в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache, веб-сервер

Мне нужно чтобы страница "site.ru/page.php" открывалась по адресу "site.ru/page".

Для этого я пишу в htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Редирект происходит и .php отрезается. Но страница page.php не отркрывается. Вместо этого я поулчаю 404 ошибку. Почему так происходит и как это сделать правильно?

Такое решение так же не подходит, потому что оно позвволяет открывать страницу в двух вариантах - page.php и просто page:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Моя же задача в том, чтобы страница открывалась по адресу /page, а при открытии адреса /page.php происходило перенаправление на /page.

Comment: Возможно вас интересует тема "PHP-роутинг (Routing) "

Comment: @ВладленВожжаев то есть средствами htaccess мою задачу решить нельзя?